# Does it exist a way to find one side of a triangle in polygon other than using similarity?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

Using the figure from below find $EB$. Assume $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles where $AB=AC$ and $\overline{BN} \parallel \overline{AC}$. Find $EB$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&6\,cm\\
2.&8\,cm\\
3.&10\,cm\\
4.&12\,cm\\
5.&11\,cm\\
\end{array}$

What I attempted to do is sumarized in the figure from below:

[image: Sketch of the solution]

As it can be seen I redrawn the figure so it can describe better what it is mentioned in the passage of the problem.

From this part. I relied on triangle similarity.

This would meant:

$\triangle ABE \sim \triangle BED$

Hence:

$\frac{6}{x}=\frac{x}{24}$

Solving this:

$x^2=6\times 24$

Which makes $x=12\,cm$

This later answer does check with the official answer from my book. But since this question is placed before introducing the concept of triangle similarity I am wondering if it could be solved relying using fundamentals of bisector angles and perpendicular bisector segment concepts. Can it be solved only using those?.

As it can be noted, some information is unused which makes me to believe was intentionally put there to use the above mentioned concepts.

All and all, is my solution correct?. I'm not good in this topic thus I need assistance on it. Please, **include a drawing in your answer** as it could require some construction.

Comment: In the text of your answer, you have stated $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle BED$. Did you mean $\triangle ABE \sim \triangle BED$?

Comment: @YNK Thank you for pointing this. I fixed it in my question. As you correctly indicated.

Answer (score 1):

From your diagram, since $\Delta ABN$ is isosceles, $BN = 24$ cm.

We can find $DE$ using Pythaogras, which is $\sqrt{x^2-6^2}$. Similarly, $AE = \sqrt{24^2 - x^2}$.

Now since $\Delta ABE = \Delta NBE$, then we have:

$$\frac{1}{2} BN \cdot DE = \frac{1}{2} BE \cdot AE$$
$$\Rightarrow 24 \sqrt{x^2 - 6^2} = x \sqrt{24^2- x^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow 24^2 (x^2 - 6^2) = x^2 (24^2 - x^2)$$
$$\Rightarrow 24^2 x^2 - 24^2 \cdot 6^2 = 24^2 x^2 = -x^4$$
$$\Rightarrow x^4 = 24^2 \cdot 6^2 \Rightarrow x = ±12.$$

$x$ cannot be $-12$. Now for $x = 12$, the LHS equals the RHS when we plug it in, so $\boxed{x = 12}$.

Comment: You mentioned about $\triangle ABE \cong \triangle NBE$ **How exactly did you prove this**?. I'm sorry but I'm struggling with this concept of congruence. You spotted it but I couldn't because I don't know which of the cases applies here. The other thing which I assume is that $BN=24$ but **why**?. Is it because $BN \parallel AC$ this **makes automatically** $BN=AC$?. Am I getting the right picture?. Can you help me with those doubts please?

Comment: I am using ASA (angle-side-angle) congruence, which states that if 2 angles and the side between those angles are equal, the triangles are congruent. $\angle ABE = \angle NBE$, $BE = BE$, and $\angle BEA = \angle BEN$.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell You have asked why $BN=24$. That is because $\triangle ANB$ is an isosceles triangle, i.e. $\measuredangle BAN = \measuredangle ANB = \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

How about using $\sin \beta$ from two different triangles (ABE and DBE).

Comment: I think trigonometry is out of the question here.

Comment: @TobyMak Sure, the intended approach here was to rely only in euclidean geometry postulates.

Answer (score 0):

Directly or indirectly trigonometry will get in.

Due to the parallelism of sides and equality of forces ( makes for an isosceles triangle) in a parallelogram we can conclude that action of force vectors AB,AC
is now a special case ... of a rhombus.

The rhombus diagonals cut at $90^{\circ}...$ convenient trigonometry of a triangle.

$$ BE=\dfrac{6}{\sin \theta}= 24 \sin \theta  $$
$$ \sin ^2\theta = \dfrac14 $$
$$ \sin \theta = \dfrac12\to \theta = 30^{\circ}$$

We can verify that $BD$ is half of its half in length computed from a $(30,60,90) $ degrees standard right triangle:

$$ 24 \cos 60^{\circ}\cos 60^{\circ} =6 $$

So there are two equilateral triangles of side $24$ in the diagram shown below:

[image]

$BE= 12, $ the answer is Option 4

( Please ignore the circular arcs drawn during construction.)

Comment: Interesting solution. Although as I indicated in the heading of my question. My intention was to ask for a method free of trygonometry and relying only in euclidean geometry postulates.